# iOS7 - AVAssetExportSession trimmed exported file shows wrong duration

Tags: ios, ios7, avassetexportsession

This was working fine in iOS 6, but in iOS 7, after I export a portion of a song using AVAssetExportSession to a file, the exported file's duration is wrong in AVAudioPlayer, but correct in AVURLAsset.

AVAudioPlayer incorrectly reports the duration as the whole song duration.

I'm exporting files using steps from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1730/_index.html

and checking the durations as below:

`AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:outputURL options:nil];
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration; // shows correct`

and

`AVAudioPlayer* avAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:outputURL error:nil];
    NSTimeInterval duration = avAudioPlayer.duration; // shows wrong`

Interestingly, if I play the exported file in iTunes, it also shows the wrong (whole) duration.

I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Could this be a bug in iOS7?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same exact problem here

Comment: Same issue with video. Any ideas?

Comment: @themyoung: Did you able to solve this problem, I have same issue.

Comment: I haven't solved the problem, let me know if you come across any possible solutions.

Comment: well it seems it has been fixed in iOS version 7.1.